# Strange Maps output

Tags: templates, add-on

I'm having trouble getting [Maps](https://addons.reinos.nl/maps) to display the map correctly in my template. The basic template setup is like this:

```
{stash:embed name="layouts:global"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_1}"}

  {exp:stash:set name="st_content" type="snippet"}

    …

  {/exp:stash:set}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My field is `{centre_address}`. If I just add that within `st_content` I get nothing.

If I have:

```
{exp:reinos_maps:html_header}
{exp:reinos_maps:map center:address="Brisbane,Australia"}
  {maps:add_marker address="{centre_address}"}
{/exp:reinos_maps:map}
{exp:reinos_maps:html_footer}
```

I get a map, but it doesn't show the correct marker, it's centred on the Brisbane CBD.

If I do this:

```
{centre_address}

{exp:reinos_maps:html_header}
{exp:reinos_maps:map center:address="Brisbane,Australia"}
  {maps:add_marker address="{centre_address}"}
{/exp:reinos_maps:map}
{exp:reinos_maps:html_footer}
```

I get *two* maps: the first is a map showing the correct marker, and the next is the same as in the previous example. Anyone know why that might be?

Also, I want to be able to get the address that's been entered into the Maps fieldtype, but it's unclear from the docs how to do that.